# Apex Controller to get the total no of Accounts and Opportunities group by Owner Name

Tags: apex, soql, aggregateresult

I have a requirement to get a table as below,
[image]

I was creating an apex controller as below, but its showing issues, May i know where i get wrong ?

```
public class AccountController {
    public <Account> getAccountsWithOwners() {
        List<Account> accountsWithOwners = [SELECT Count(Id), Owner.Name, (SELECT(count(Id) FROM Opportunities) FROM Account GROUP BY Owner.Name];
        return accountsWithOwners;                                                              
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sourav, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and read [ask]. As written, this post is not very specific and will not likely receive a useful answer. Please **[edit]** it to be more detailed than "showing issues".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue with the query is that aggregate queries are supported only at root level.
Inner query for counting opportunities will not work in this case.

We can execute 2 queries for getting the desired results as below :

1 Query Accounts based on Owner.Name as below :

```
AggregateResult[] accountResults = [SELECT Count(Id),Owner.Name FROM Account GROUP BY Owner.Name ORDER BY Owner.Name];
```

2 Query Opportunities based on the related account owner field as below :

```
AggregateResult[] opportunityResults = [SELECT count(id), Account.Owner.Name FROM Opportunity GROUP BY Account.Owner.Name ORDER BY Account.Owner.Name];
```

In both the queries we are using the same `Owner.name` field for aggregating as well as ordering which enables us to conclude that 1st result of `query 2` will be the count of opportunities for 1st result of `query 1` and same for other results as well.

Edit : Either have separate methods or for returning both results from the method,
Using a map to store both query results.

```
public Map<String, List<AggregateResult>> getAccountsAndOppsWithOwners() {

Map<String, List<AggregateResult>> aggResultsMap = new Map<String, List<AggregateResult>>();

AggregateResult[] accountResults = [SELECT Count(Id),Owner.Name FROM Account GROUP BY Owner.Name ORDER BY Owner.Name]; 
AggregateResult[] opportunityResults = [SELECT count(id), Account.Owner.Name FROM Opportunity GROUP BY Account.Owner.Name ORDER BY Account.Owner.Name];   

aggResultsMap.put('accounts', accountResults);
aggResultsMap.put('opportunities', opportunityResults);

return aggResultsMap;
}
```

Comment: If i am using the below, its showing me an "unreachable statement" error. whats can be the issue?          public class AccountController {
    public List <AggregateResult>getAccountsWithOwners(){
  List <AggregateResult> accountResults = [SELECT Count(Id),Owner.Name FROM Account GROUP BY Owner.Name ORDER BY Owner.Name]; 
       List <AggregateResult> opportunityResults = [SELECT count(id), Account.Owner.Name FROM Opportunity GROUP BY Account.Owner.Name ORDER BY Account.Owner.Name];
        return accountResults;  
        return opportunityResults;
    }
}

Comment: while using only the account is working

Comment: Making two separate methods working. Can't we make both query under one method ?

Comment: You cannot return from a function twice. Updated the answer for using only 1 method. My preference would be to use separate methods.

Comment: Thanks Rohit. It worked